# unable to get webhook data after completing the docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have sent the document for signing to a signer using this code from my local instance

```
print_r(send_document_for_signing());

function send_document_for_signing(){
    # The document $fileNamePath will be sent to be signed by <signer_name>
    # Settings
    # Fill in these constants
    #
    # Obtain an OAuth access token from https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator
    $accessToken = 'myAccessTokes';
    # Obtain your accountId from demo.docusign.com -- the account id is shown in the drop down on the
    # upper right corner of the screen by your picture or the default picture.
    $accountId = '';
    # Recipient Information:
    $signerName = '';
    $signerEmail = '';
    # The document you wish to send. Path is relative to the root directory of this repo.
    $fileNamePath = 'test/Docs/SignTest1.pdf';

    # The API base_path
    $basePath = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';

    # Constants
    $appPath = getcwd();

    #
    # Step 1. The envelope definition is created.
    #         One signHere tab is added.
    #         The document path supplied is relative to the working directory
    #
    # Create the component objects for the envelope definition...
    $contentBytes = file_get_contents($appPath . "/" . $fileNamePath);
    $base64FileContent =  base64_encode ($contentBytes);
    $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([ # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $base64FileContent,
        'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '1' # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);

    $envelope_events = [
        (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent"),
    ];

    $recipient_events = [
        (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Completed"),

    ];

    $event_notification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EventNotification();
    $event_notification->setUrl('mysite/docusign_test/test.php');
    $event_notification->setLoggingEnabled("true");
    $event_notification->setRequireAcknowledgment("true");
    $event_notification->setUseSoapInterface("false");
    $event_notification->setIncludeCertificateWithSoap("false");
    $event_notification->setSignMessageWithX509Cert("false");
    $event_notification->setIncludeDocuments("true");
    $event_notification->setIncludeEnvelopeVoidReason("true");
    $event_notification->setIncludeTimeZone("true");
    $event_notification->setIncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField("true");
    $event_notification->setIncludeDocumentFields("true");
    $event_notification->setIncludeCertificateOfCompletion("true");
    $event_notification->setEnvelopeEvents($envelope_events);
    $event_notification->setRecipientEvents($recipient_events);

    # The signer object
    $signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
        'email' => $signerEmail, 'name' => $signerName, 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"
    ]);

    # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
    $envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
        'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
        'documents' => [$document], # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
        'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]), # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
        'status' => "sent", # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
    ]);
    $envelopeDefinition->setEventNotification($event_notification);
    #
    #  Step 2. Create/send the envelope.
    #
    $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($basePath);
    $config->addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " . $accessToken);
    $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
    $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
    $results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);
    return $results;
```

It is successfully sending the email to the signer and after completing the document i got email of completed.

as i have assigned a `url`  on which i want to receive my response on completed document because i want to do some processing there. But it is not returning the response and i am unable to fetch the completed document response.

Edit : i have also made the test file on server where i want to get the response and read it.

code in `test.php` file :

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

file_put_contents('data.txt', $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for EventNotifications must be secured with HTTPS. If you're using `http://{url}/` it will fail.

Comment: it works if i added https server and i am able to get my response. Thanks alot. I have a question is it possible to disable the secure url ? i mean can i use http only?

Comment: No, HTTPS is mandatory. More info is available here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-https-only

Answer (score 1):

what is the url you used for your webhook?
there's a way to check connect logs to see if there was an attempt to call your code and if it worked ok or not. This should allow you to isolate the issue a bit more (you can also confirm your code was called by using debugging techniques)

see here - https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect for information about connect logs

Comment: Hello thank you for your comment. actually i am not using connect api. rather a simple webhook `url` in `event notification` array.

more over i am using `http://{someip}/test.php`

Comment: oh, so you are talking about redirectUrl? does it come back to your app? but without the additional information?

Comment: i am talking about this `$event_notification->setUrl('mysite/docusign_test/test.php');` to which it return the envelope details after completing.

Comment: this is connect. but you said you are not using connect. So I'm confused. It appears you are using connect.

Comment: problem was in https and it did not work without https thank you much help provided.